# How to loop through a firebase database after a specific key name that matches an element's ID?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the picture below I have 5 events added to my calendar, the name of the key (for example 13No (which stands for 13th of November)) is what I want to search for when looping.

When I click a delete button, I want to check the parent's ID and compare it to all the key names in the database, then when a match is found I want this key to be deleted from the database. Since I'm new to Firebase I'm not sure how to loop through the database, so help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: I changed the names of the keys to be the same as the ID I want to search for, to make it easier, but I still can't get the loop to work.

[image: firebase example]

Here is the function that should execute the delete:

```js
var myDataRef = new Firebase('Removed for safety reasons'); //The name of my database

function deleteEvent() {

    var parent = this.parentNode.id; //Grabs the button parent's ID

    for (i = 0; i < myDataRef.length; i++) { //Tried a for loop but didn't work with myDataRef.length

        //If parent matches myDataRef[i]
        //Then delete myDataRef[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: `myDataRef.length` does not work on a Firebase ref. You're probably looking for `numChildren`, which is available on a Firebase snapshot: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/numchildren.html.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hm, this is the problem though, how do I get a snapshot of the entire database without changing anything in it? Because in my head, I have to grab all keys in the database, count how many there are, then loop over these keys to find a match with the ID, then and only then remove the key that matched. Am I going about it all wrong?

Comment: I can't really follow what you're saying. But if you know what they clicked, just do myDataRef.child('13no').remove(). Of course substituting the actual value of eventFay for '13no'.

Comment: What is the actual use case here? This looks extremely convoluted; it would help to know what the exact, specific, and detailed constraints we are trying to meet are.